# Modification in the Ford-Fulkerson method

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, ford-fulkerson

I want to find, among all minimum cuts in a flow network G with
integral capacities, one that contains the smallest number of edges. How can we
modify the capacities of G to create a new flow network G' in which any minimum
cut in G' is a minimum cut with the smallest number of edges in G.
Source - Cormen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets say the graph `G` has `n` vertices.

We define the capacity for an arc `e'` in `G'` which corresponds to the arc `e` in `G` as `c(e') = c(e) * n + 1`.

Therefore the value of a cut in `G'` is exactly `n` times the value of the cut in `G` + the number of edges in the cut.

Lets say we have now a minimum cut in `G'` with value `n * x + a`. That means the value of the cut in `G` is x. If there would exist a cut in `G` with a smaller value `y < x` this cut would have a value of `n * y + b <= n * (y+1) <= n * x < n * x + a` which is a contradiction to the fact that the cut with value `n * x + a` was minimum in `G'`. We just proved that every minimum cut in `G'` is also a minimum cut in `G`. But then it follows that a minimum cut in `G'` is a minimum cut in `G` and has a minimum number of edges of all minimum cuts in `G`.